# Is it possible to become fluent in pre-12th century English?

Tags: learning-methods, resource-request, self-learning, english, proficiency

I would really like to learn to speak Old English, but it seems that spelling and pronunciation weren't exactly standardized in the early medieval times. In fact, I'm not sure we know much about Old English in general. Is it possible to become fluent in pre-12th century English with what information we currently have about it? And if so, are there any resources you could point me to?

Ic þancie þē (Thanks)!

Comment: Strictly speaking, fluency and proficiency are two different things. Proficiency refers to the level you've reached (e.g. CEFR level), while fluency refers to the easy witch which you can use the knowledge you have acquired (regardless of level). Which if these two do you have in mind?

Comment: @Tsundoku Fluency. I don't really care about official standards, as I don't expect Old English to necessarily help me get a career. I just want to speak it without having to think too hard about it. I want it to be my second language.

Answer (score 1):

As far as if it is possible to become in old English. the answer is yes. Look up professor Alexander Arguelles. Not only is he fluent in old English, he claims to know over 95% of the words in old English. As far as resources, I will direct you again to Professor Arguelles he has a YouTube channel where he talks about the resources hes uses to learn languages